# How to change or override the tooltip in JavaFX ColorPicker

Tags: javafx-8, color-picker

I am using JavaFX ColorPicker in my application. As per my requirements,  I have mapped the default colors on the color picker to a number. I want this number to be displayed as tooltip on hover over the color instead of hex value of the color. How can I achieve this?

//Part of Code

public void handleNodes(Circle circularNode) {

```
    final Delta offset = new Delta();

    circularNode.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override 
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            ((Circle)(event.getSource())).setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        }
    });

    circularNode.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override 
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                System.out.println("Right click");

                Circle parent = ((Circle)(event.getSource()));

                final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                MenuItem editLabel = new MenuItem("Edit Label");
                editLabel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                      System.out.println("Edit Label");

                      final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
                      colorPicker.setStyle("-fx-border-radius: 10 10 10 10;" 
                                            + "-fx-background-radius: 10 10 10 10;");
                      colorPicker.setValue((Color) parent.getFill());
                                      colorPicker.showingProperty().addListener((obs,b,b1)->{
                          if(b1){
                              PopupWindow popupWindow = getPopupWindow();
                              javafx.scene.Node popup =            popupWindow.getScene().getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
                              popup.lookupAll(".color-rect").stream()
                                  .forEach(rect->{
                                      Color c = (Color)((Rectangle)rect).getFill();
                                      Tooltip.install(rect.getParent(), new Tooltip("Custom tip for "+c.toString()));
                                  });
                          }
                      });

                      panelMain.getChildren().add(colorPicker);                       
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code posted by the OP after my first answer, and due to the substancial changes in the problem addressed, I'm adding a new answer that covers both situations:

- The `ColorPicker` is embedded in the main scene, as a regular node
- The `ColorPicker` is embedded in a `ContextMenu`

In the second situation, the proposed solution for the first one is no longer valid, since the window found will be the one with the context menu.

A task is required to keep looking for windows until the one with the `ComboBoxPopupControl` is found.

This is a full runnable example:

```
public class ColorPickerFinder extends Application {

    ExecutorService findWindowExecutor = createExecutor("FindWindow");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        AnchorPane panCircles = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(panCircles, 400, 400);

        final Random random = new Random();
        IntStream.range(0,5).boxed().forEach(i->{
            final Circle circle= new Circle(20+random.nextInt(80), 
                Color.rgb(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));
            circle.setTranslateX(100+random.nextInt(200));
            circle.setTranslateY(100+random.nextInt(200));
            panCircles.getChildren().add(circle);
        });
        panCircles.setPrefSize(400, 400);
        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();

        panCircles.getChildren().add(colorPicker);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // We add listeners AFTER showing the stage, as we are looking for nodes 
        // by css selectors, these will be available only after the stage is shown
        colorPicker.showingProperty().addListener((obs,b,b1)->{
            if(b1){
                // No need for task in this case
                getPopupWindow();
            }
        });

        panCircles.getChildren().stream()
                .filter(c->c instanceof Circle)
                .map(c->(Circle)c)
                .forEach(circle->{
            circle.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
                if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)){
                    // We need a task, since the first window found is the ContextMenu one
                    findWindowExecutor.execute(new WindowTask());

                    final ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
                    picker.setStyle("-fx-border-radius: 10 10 10 10;" 
                                          + "-fx-background-radius: 10 10 10 10;");
                    picker.setValue((Color)(circle.getFill()));
                    picker.valueProperty().addListener((obs,c0,c1)->circle.setFill(c1));

                    final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                    MenuItem editLabel = new MenuItem();
                    contextMenu.getItems().add(editLabel);
                    editLabel.setGraphic(picker);
                    contextMenu.show(panCircles,e.getScreenX(),e.getScreenY());
                }
            });
        });

    }

    private PopupWindow getPopupWindow() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
        final Iterator<Window> windows = Window.impl_getWindows();

        while (windows.hasNext()) {
            final Window window = windows.next();
            if (window instanceof PopupWindow) {
                if(window.getScene()!=null && window.getScene().getRoot()!=null){ 
                    Parent root = window.getScene().getRoot();
                    if(root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().size()>0){
                        Node popup = root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
                        if(popup.lookup(".combo-box-popup")!=null){

                            // only process ComboBoxPopupControl
                            Platform.runLater(()->{
                                popup.lookupAll(".color-rect").stream()
                                    .forEach(rect->{
                                        Color c = (Color)((Rectangle)rect).getFill();
                                        Tooltip.install(rect.getParent(), 
                                            new Tooltip("Custom tip for "+c.toString()));
                                    });
                            });
                            return (PopupWindow)window;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class WindowTask extends Task<Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            boolean found=false;
            while(!found){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                found=(getPopupWindow()!=null);
            }
            return null;
        }

    } 

    private ExecutorService createExecutor(final String name) {
        ThreadFactory factory = r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setName(name);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        };
        return Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(factory);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

This will be the result after right clicking on a circle, and clicking on the color picker:

[image: Color Picker on ContextMenu]

Comment: Absolutely Perfect!! I couldn't have done it myself. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks, it was really a ver hard question... and it is a really hacky answer. By the way, don't click on custom color, there's a bug and it will give you a NPE. Maybe you could try to disable it.

Comment: Ohhh the good part is I have disabled that link. I need only the default colors on the color picker. So now everything works exactly how I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a hacky answer.

The first problem: you have to find the popup node on the scene once it shows up. But you won't... since its not in the same window!

Having a deep look at how [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) does it, the trick is getting the list of windows at that moment, but using a deprectated method:

```
private PopupWindow getPopupWindow() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") final Iterator<Window> windows = Window.impl_getWindows();
    while (windows.hasNext()) {
        final Window window = windows.next();
        if (window instanceof PopupWindow) {
            return (PopupWindow)window;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once you have the popup window, we can now check for all the `Rectangle` nodes using `lookupAll` and the CSS selector `color-rect`, to get their color, and install the tooltip over its parent container:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
    StackPane root = new StackPane(picker);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    picker.showingProperty().addListener((obs,b,b1)->{
        if(b1){
            PopupWindow popupWindow = getPopupWindow();
            Node popup = popupWindow.getScene().getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
            popup.lookupAll(".color-rect").stream()
                .forEach(rect->{
                    Color c = (Color)((Rectangle)rect).getFill();
                    Tooltip.install(rect.getParent(), new Tooltip("Custom tip for "+c.toString()));
                });
        }
    });
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Color picker with custom tooltip]

Comment: yes…the issue is with Window.impl_getWindows(); It is giving null. Any alternative to this?

Comment: It's deprecated, but it's working for me under JDK 8u25. What's the problem? Any exception?

Comment: I just get one window from Window.impl_getWindows() and is not the PopupWindow. So the method returns null.

Comment: If I call `getPopupWindow()` after showing the stage, it gives the main stage, and after clicking the color picker gives me this popup window: `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl$1@1d0fc4ab`. Are you running this on an isolated new project? Try it to check if it works on your system.

Comment: ok let me try again…..This a part of an existing project…..Basically once the stage opens, I have a circle, on click of it this color picker opens up…I have done exactly as you have shown…but still it detects one window - javafx.stage.Stage@40a02f62

Comment: We can't discuss it any longer over comments. Could you please update your question with your code or some of it, so I can see what is different in your code? You say you have a circle, where is the color picker? Over the circle?

Comment: Are you trying to add the color picker as a menu item of a context menu for every circle? Or is it place on a different pane?

Comment: Yes Im adding color picker on click of menu item in context menu every time( Circle -> ContextMenu -> Colorpicker). I did try your code separately and it works perfectly fine. i guess it has something do do with the way my code works.

Comment: The problem now is the window it finds is `ContextMenu`, and depending on how you set the listeners, it may find `ComboBoxPopupControl`. I've got some work in progress, tomorrow I'll try to post it.