# Show Colorpicker from Contextmenu

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to show Colorpicker from Context Menu:

```
ColorPicker colorssPicker = new ColorPicker();

    final MenuItem resizeItem = new MenuItem("Option 1");
    resizeItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {

        }
    });

    final MenuItem resizesItem = new MenuItem();
    resizesItem.setGraphic(colorssPicker);
    resizesItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {

        }
    });

    final ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

    menu.getItems().addAll(resizeItem, resizesItem);

    sc.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton()))
            {
                menu.show(primaryStage, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is not working, I can't see Colorpicker when I click on the Contextmenu "Choose Color". What is the proper way to implement this?

I get this result:

[image]

Comment: And where do you add `colorssPicker` to the menu? Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26972427/3956070), and this line: `editLabel.setGraphic(picker);`

Comment: I updated the code but the end result is nit very good. Can I somehow fix this?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Can I somehow make it look like this https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/img/color-picker-css2.png and place it at the position of the text into the Contextmenu?

Comment: So you want to get rid of the button style and remove the text of the menuitem?

Comment: @JoséPereda Correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet will let you show a `ColorPicker` control embedded into a `ContextMenu`.

You can style it so it doesn't look like a button, by setting its backgound color.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    final ColorPicker colorssPicker = new ColorPicker();
    colorssPicker.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");

    final MenuItem otherItem = new MenuItem(null, new Label("Other item"));

    final MenuItem resizeItem = new MenuItem(null,colorssPicker);
    resizeItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(colorssPicker.getValue(),null,null)));
        }
    });

    final ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(otherItem,resizeItem);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event){
            if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton())){
                menu.show(primaryStage, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
            }
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: ColorPicker]

Comment: Thanks! By the way when I chose "Custom Color" from the color picker I get Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException Looks like that there is a internal bug in JavaFX.

Comment: Yes, it's already [known](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/JMY-275), but not fixed...

Comment: There's no workaround keeping the actual control. I've solved it by creating my [custom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27180647/3956070) color picker control based on the original one.